# Working out time inbetween time to percentage Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, animation, math

I'm trying to work out a percentage from 0 - 100 from a part of HTML video

When the HTML video hits 5.89 secs I would like the animation to complete on 10.05 im having troubles doing this so far i have worked out the percentage of the time below

So there is 4.16 inbetween the times stated and it works out to be 1% is 0.041600000000000005

I have added the current time into the function becuase i need to work out what percent the video is on while its playing

```
var animationOneStart = 5.89;
var animationOneEnd = 10.05;


function perentageTime(animationStart,animationEnd,currentTime){
  var timeInbetween = animationEnd - animationStart;

  a = 1/100;
  b = a*timeInbetween;

  return b;
}
```

I'm having troubles working out the percentage while it playing would anyone be able to help me please?

Thanks

Comment: First of all, convert times into seconds.  `5.89 != 5:89`

Comment: So what is the issue you are having? Your code returns .04160000000000001, you worried about the `0000000000001` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula for percentage is `(currentValue / maxValue) * 100` so, in your case will be `(currentTime / timeInbetween) * 100`

Here is an example:

```js
var animationOneStart = 5.89;
var animationOneEnd = 10.05;

function perentageTime(animationStart,animationEnd,currentTime){
  var maxValue = animationEnd - animationStart;
  var ret = (currentTime / maxValue) * 100;
  return ret.toFixed(2);
}

var percentage = perentageTime(animationOneStart, animationOneEnd, 1);
console.log(percentage);
```

This will work only if `currentTime` starts from `0`, if it starts from `animationOneStart`, you'll need to use `((currentTime - animationOneStart) / maxValue) * 100`